# How do I trigger the "input" event on v-text-field when testing a component using Vitest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vuetify.js, vitest

I need to write a test in Vitest (^0.30) that when a user inputs a date into a Vue (2.6.14) component that wraps a Vuetify (~2.3.8) v-text-field, that both the v-model is updated and the @input event is emitted (I don't need to check that the event itself is emitted nor that it called the handler, I just need it to do it so I get the effect of the event handler). Right now neither seem to be working.

```
            <v-text-field
                v-model="localDatePicker.formattedDisplayValue"
                v-bind="attrs"
                :placeholder="placeholder"
                dense
                hide-details
                :append-icon="appendCalendar ? 'far fa-calendar' : ''"
                :error="errorState"
                :disabled="disableTextField"
                :label="label"
                :outlined="textFieldOutlined"
                :prepend-inner-icon="!appendCalendar ? 'far fa-calendar' : ''"
                :rules="required ? [isValidMMDDYYYYDate] : []"
                v-on="on"
                @input="onTextDateChanged"
            />

    const onTextDateChanged = () => {
        if (isValidMMDDYYYYDate(props.dueDatePicker.formattedDisplayValue))
            localDatePicker.value.pickerComponentValue = parseDate(
                props.dueDatePicker.formattedDisplayValue
            );
        updateParentDatePicker();
    };

        it.only('sets the resolved date', async () => {
            expect(
                // @ts-ignore
                wrapper.vm.resolvedDatePicker.formattedDisplayValue
            ).toMatch('');
            expect(
                // @ts-ignore
                wrapper.vm.resolvedDatePicker.pickerComponentValue
            ).toMatch('');

            // @ts-ignore
            wrapper.vm.selectedProblemStatus = wrapper.vm.problemStatusItems[2];
            await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
            const resolvedDateTextFieldDatePicker = wrapper.findComponent(TextFieldDatePicker);
            const resolvedDateVTextField = resolvedDateTextFieldDatePicker.findComponent(
                VTextField
            );
            const resolvedDateInput = resolvedDateVTextField.find('input');
            // await resolvedDateTextFieldDatePicker.setValue('4/10/2023');
            // await resolvedDateVTextField.setValue('4/10/2023');
            await resolvedDateInput.setValue('4/10/2023');
            await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
            // await resolvedDateInput.trigger('input');
            // await resolvedDateInput.trigger('change');
            // await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

            expect(
                // @ts-ignore
                wrapper.vm.resolvedDatePicker.formattedDisplayValue
            ).toMatch('4/10/2023');
            expect(
                // @ts-ignore
                wrapper.vm.resolvedDatePicker.pickerComponentValue
            ).toMatch('2023-04-10');
        });
```

resolved date input > when problem status is resolved > sets the resolved date
AssertionError: expected '' to include '4/10/2023'

I've tried setting the value of the html  control inside the v-text-field and I've tried manually triggering the change and/or input events. I'm expecting the `onTextDateChanged` input event handler to get triggered so that it updates another part of the model (parsing the input into another format/object). It doesn't seem to be binding the value to the model nor running the input event handler.

Comment: are you shallow mounting the component for test? shallow mount may result in inconsistencies while palying with input or events.